# php page stops loading on PDO/query error

Tags: php, apache, pdo

my pages are stopping loading if there is an error in a query or anything.

example apache log :

```
[Sat Aug 19 20:54:47.756528 2017] [php7:error] [pid 5180:tid 1832] [client ::1:52169] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '43334478' for key 'PRIMARY' in C:\\Users\\Olivier\\Downloads\\UniServerZ\\www\\admin\\user_admin.php:113\nStack trace:\n#0 C:\\Users\\Olivier\\Downloads\\UniServerZ\\www\\admin\\user_admin.php(113): PDOStatement->execute()\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\Users\\Olivier\\Downloads\\UniServerZ\\www\\admin\\user_admin.php on line 113, referer: http://localhost/admin/user_admin.php?adduser
```

my code is something very simple for each query, but in the example above i have something like :

```
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        if ($stmt) {
            echo '<p><font color="green">User successfully created</font></p>';
        } else {
            echo '<p><font color="red">Error while creating user</font></p>';
            echo '<p><font color="red">Error is : '.$stmt->errorCode().'</font></p>';
        }
```

and naturlly the last line does not work, if there is an error during the insert (of any kind, in the example it's just because the ID specified already exists in the database), the page just stops loading when the error happens, and i don't want that.

is there a way to fix that ? and make the page continue loading even if there is a query error ? and make PDO display the error ?

for information, i'm connecting to the DB like that :

```
function _ConnectDB($db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass) {

try {
   $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_pass);
   $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
   return $conn;
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
   echo "Connection to the database failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

}
```

is this coming from the ERRMODE_EXCEPTION i'm specifying during the connection ? or some PHP.ini parameters ?

thanks!
regards

Comment: the error is self-explanatory :- `duplicate entry '43334478' for key 'PRIMARY'`. you can't duplicate primary key.

Comment: But the exception is caught so other than that the site should still load @AlivetoDie

Comment: It's `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException:`  fatal error cause break-down of the system(means stop execution)

Comment: @alive : i know the error, i generated this error on purpose.. (using an ID already existing) but i want to find a way to grab the error in the page, and so that the page does not block/stops loading, you are not answering my question at all, sorry

Comment: Why can't you just have a try catch statement

Comment: i could try, but i'm sure this problem is so simple to solve and someone will come up with a known solution (it's probably not a problem, just a PHP or PDO behavior that can be changed..)

Answer (score 0):

It's called an exception (http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) and you should catch it to display an error. Uncaught exceptions will break the code execution, because this is what they do. Exception means something bad happened and the program can not continue untill you catch it (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp) and tell your program what to do it such case.

Comment: thank you, so there is no need to treat it normally and make the page not crash ?

Comment: What do you mean by "normally" ?